# Why do we rescale and renormalize fields?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, statistical-mechanics, field-theory, renormalization, phase-transition

The Renormalization procedure is generically broken down into three steps (see eg Kardar Statistical Fields Chapter 4)

1) Coarse Grain (Typically this amounts to integrating out the fast Fourier modes $\frac{-\Lambda}{b} <|q|<\Lambda$)

2) Rescale Lengths ($x'=\frac{x}{b}$)

3) Renormalize Fields ($\phi'(x)=z\phi(x)$)

I am having trouble understanding why one would perform steps 2 and 3 in the context of a continuous phase transition. My understanding thus far is that at the critical point the system is statistically self similar on all length scales and therefore if we construct an effective Hamiltonian for the longer wavelength modes of the system the coupling constants should not change. Step 1 seems to be all that is necessary then. Steps 2 and 3 seem to only be a change of co-ordinates and a field redefinition, both of which cannot affect the coupling constants (if a coupling is significant in one co-ordinate system is significant in all co-ordinate systems). However it is generally step 2 that suppresses higher derivative terms, so it cannot be just a co-ordinate transformation.

Why do we perform steps 2 and 3?

Comment: Because you want to do this procedure repeatedly, you need to make the system look functionally the same as you started with. Rescaling lengths gives you back the same integral, and renormalizing fields is necessary to maintain the interpretation of the field (think LSZ normalization).

Comment: But one can in practice carry out the procedure repeatedly with or without rescaling lengths. Of all the continuum examples I've worked through so far (Gaussian Model, Wilson Fischer Fixed Point, Spherical Model), it is as easy to infer the result of repeated momentum  integrations with or without rescaling lengths.

Comment: True, but then you would have issues defining what you mean by fixed point. For example, if you coarse grain an infinite number of times, your final integral must be 0 because your limits of integration will both be 0. In order for that limit to be well-defined you need to rescale. One should think of the renormalization group (as described by Kardar) as mapping the original problem to an equivalent problem only with modified coefficients. I haven't thought too deeply about the continuum models yet though tbh.

Comment: My mistake, the specific examples I was looking at were easy to eyeball the result of many integrals, but in general, it is way more expedient to transform the co-ordinates and fields to make the iteration procedure as simple as possible. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Aaron points out, the coordinate transform and field redefinition are done to make iterating the integral in step 1 as simple as possible.